# Why won't Metro applications start on the Windows 8 preview?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8-preview, modern-ui

I have installed the Windows 8 Developer Preview edition on **Oracle VM Virtual Box**.
After installation was complete I loaded the new O.S and was directed to the windows new Titled UI with all the default tiles shown.

But only the IE and Windows explorer tile responded to the mouse clicks. Other titles were not opening.

***Following Tiles opened after clicking on the tile:***

- IE
- Control Panel
- Desktop
- Windows Explorer

All other tiles don't seem to respond to the click event!

Does any one know why this occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the resolution to at least 1024x768 to launch Metro apps.

**Source:** [Microsoft Developer Network  - Windows 8 Developer Preview - System Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516)