# Setting a SOCKS Proxy for Metro Apps in Windows 8 Release Preview

Tags: proxy, windows-8-preview, socks-proxy, socks5

I'm using [Proxifier](http://proxifier.com/) application to set a SOCKS proxy in my Windows 7. I have set several rules for it. For instance I have set a few domains to use a SOCKS proxy, some connections are direct, etc.

The problem is that when I tried to install Proxifier in Windows 8 Release Preview, all my MetroStyle apps stopped working. There are a few threads in SuperUser but their solution only work for Consumer Preview. Also, I'm willing to keep using rule-based proxy setting (in contrast to using a single proxy for all my connections through Internet Options).

Is there any software which is able to do this in Windows 8 Consumer Preview?

Link to related articles:

[How to setup a proxy for Modern UI (aka Metro) Apps in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/397577/how-to-setup-a-proxy-for-metro-ui-apps-in-windows-8-consumer-preview)

[Why won't Metro applications start on the Windows 8 preview?](https://superuser.com/questions/350284/why-wont-metro-applications-start-on-the-windows-8-preview)